# Concatenate strings in multiple csv files into one datafram along x and y axis (in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a folder with many csv files. They all look similar, they all have the same names for columns and rows. They all have strings as values in their cells. I want to concatenate them along columns AND rows so that all the strings are concatenated into their respective cells.

**Example:**

`file1.csv`

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | peter | house | ash | plane |
| b2 | carl | horse | paul | knife |
| b3 | mary | apple | linda | carrot |
| b4 | hank | car | herb | beer |

`file2.csv`

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | mark | green | hello | band |
| b2 | no | phone | spoon | goodbye |
| b3 | red | cherry | charly | hammer |
| b4 | good | yes | ok | simon |

What I want is this result with no delimiter between the string values:

`concatenated.csv`

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | peter mark | house green | ash hello | plane band |
| b2 | carl no | horse phone | paul spoon | knife goodbye |
| b3 | mary red | apple cherry | linda charly | carrot hammer |
| b4 | hank good | car yes | herb ok | beer simon |

And I don't know how to do this in pandas in a jupyter notebook.

I have tried a couple of things but all of them either kept a seperate set of rows or of columns.

Answer (score 3):

If these are your dataframes:

```
df1_data = {
    1 : ['peter', 'carl', 'mary', 'hank'],
    2 : ['house', 'horse','apple', 'car']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data)

df2_data = {
    1 : ['mark', 'no',   'red',   'good'],
    2 : ['green','phone','cherry','yes' ]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data)
```

df1:

```
       1      2
0  peter  house
1   carl  horse
2   mary  apple
3   hank    car
```

df2:

```
      1       2
0  mark   green
1    no   phone
2   red  cherry
3  good     yes
```

You can reach your requested dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df[1] = df1[1] + ' ' + df2[1]
df[2] = df1[2] + ' ' + df2[2]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            1             2
0  peter mark   house green
1     carl no   horse phone
2    mary red  apple cherry
3   hank good       car yes
```

**Loop for csv files:**

Now, if you have a lot of csv files with names like `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` and so on, you can save them all in `d` like this:

```
d = {}
for i in range(1,#N): 
  d[i] = pd.read_csv('.../file'+str(i)+'.csv')
#N is the number of csv files. (because I started from 1, you have to add 1 to N)
```

And build the dataframe you want like this:

```
concatenated_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,#N):
  concatenated_df[i] = d[1].iloc[:,i] + ' ' + d[2].iloc[:,i] + ...
#N is the number of columns here.
```

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the first column that doesn't need to be manipulated.  If you set index first before adding together you could avoid this

Comment: Yes you are right. I wasn't aware. If the first column of all csv files is the same, adding that column with my code is not difficult, thanks for your notice.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not an issue, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with [`pandas.Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) :

```
out = df1[[0]].join(df1.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(lambda v: f"{v} ").add(df2.iloc[:, 1:]))
```

Or, for a large dataset, you can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with a *listcomp* :

```
out = (
        df1[[0]]
            .join(pd.concat([df1.merge(df2, on=0)
                                 .filter(regex=f"{p}_\w").agg(" ".join, axis=1)
                                 .rename(idx) for idx, p in enumerate(range(1, len(df1.columns)), start=1)],
                            axis=1))
     )
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

    0           1             2             3              4
0  b1  peter mark   house green     ash hello     plane band
1  b2     carl no   horse phone    paul spoon  knife goodbye
2  b3    mary red  apple cherry  linda charly  carrot hammer
3  b4   hank good       car yes       herb ok     beer simon
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading many csv files into a single DF is a pretty common answer, and is the first part of your question.  You can find a suitable answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe).

After that, in an effort to allow you to perform this on all of the files at the same time, you can melt and pivot with a custom agg function like so:

import glob
import pandas as pd

```
# See the linked answer if you need help finding csv files in a different directory
all_files = glob.glob('*.csv'))
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files))


output = df.melt(id_vars='0')
           .pivot_table(index='0', 
                        columns='variable',
                        values='value',
                        aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```